# Check for location using broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, location, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

Whenever I check location settings, I can see the low usage by google maps etc. My question is can I declare a broadcast receiver such that it continuously receives location updates? As in can I check if the users location is equal to a specific location? Or will this process drain battery like anything? Is there a Broadcast Receiver Intent-Filter for location changed?
Please do help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to receive an event when a device enters a specific area, you might want to look into [Geofencing](http://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html). You can specify a location and a proximity to the location to trigger the event.

Comment: Thanks whitaay I'll look into it and let you know shortly